# How to use Google cloud platform DLP API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

Can anyone please tell me how to use Google Cloud DLP API and can I track my local system using these Google Cloud API like track info which is flow from Facebook, Gmail, Skype etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to track data flowing between those systems? I'm not aware of a way to inject yourself between them.

If you want to track what is being sent out on your local network and are looking for design ideas - one such idea could be to use a local proxy that you have configured to send all traffic through something like https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rpc/google.privacy.dlp.v2#inspectcontentrequest so that you can send up alerts if there is anything surprising.

Gmail also has a version of Cloud DLP built in for gsuite customers to automatically monitor/prevent employees from sending email with specific finding types.